# MySQL concat() in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel

I am trying to write this MySQL query in Laravel:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) LIKE '%John%'`

The idea being that records with either a `firstName` or a `lastName` of `John` will be returned

Things I have tried:

.

`$users = User::whereRaw("(CONCAT(users.firstName, ' ', users.lastName) like '%John%')");`

**Error** `The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.`

.

`$users = User::whereRaw("(CONCAT(users.firstName, ' ', users.lastName) like '%?%')",[$search])->get();`

**Returns `[]`**

.

`$users = User::whereRaw("(CONCAT(users.firstName, ' ', users.lastName) like ?)",[$search])->get();`

**Returns `[]`**

Comment: You can try to dump your raw sql by `User::whereRaw("(CONCAT(users.firstName, ' ', users.lastName) like ?)",[$search])->toSql()` and find mistake

Comment: Thanks, @xAoc I have looked at the generated SQL and made some progress.

Answer (score 0):

After examining the SQL (thanks @xAoc!) I figured out that the SQL being generated way wrong.

This appears to generate the correct SQL:

`return User::whereRaw("(CONCAT(users.firstName, ' ', users.lastName) like '%$search%')")->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Its work for me, you can try with this:

```
$search = 'John Smith';
$users = User::whereRaw("(CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) like '%$search%')")->get();
```

output look like:

> Collection {#573 ▼
>         #items: array:13 [▶]
>       }